# Calculate difference using nearest (oldest date) using same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the (simplified) database table A below which holds both the Mother Batch Purity Value and the Batch Puritys (all batches are made from the previous "Mother Batch".

I am trying to figure out how to pull out via SQL the Batch Purity and the Difference between the Batch Purity and the previous Mother Batch. The sample names always remain the same, but can be numerous batch numbers

**Table A**

```
Sample Name    |  Purity   |  Date (DD/MMM/YY)  
---------------+-----------+-----------------  
Mother Batch   |    100    |10-Oct-20  
   Batch 1     |    96     |11-Oct-20  
   Batch 2     |    94     |13-Oct-20  
Mother Batch   |    98     |14-Oct-20  
   Batch 1     |    94     |16-Oct-20  

Many thanks
Bob
```

Comment: How to find the mother? Only by the date? Or do you have a connecting column?

Comment: No just by date, so the outcome would be something (I am adding a maths columns here for example)

Batch 1      4  (100-96)
Batch 2     6    (100-4)
Batch 1     4   (98-94)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional window functions:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(date,
                max(case when samplename like 'Mother%' then date end) over (order by date)
               ) as diff
from t;
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you would use:

```
       datediff(day,
                max(case when samplename like 'Mother%' then date end) over (order by date),
                date
               ) as diff
```

Comment: And if i have further columns or sample names in that column/table? (sorry may have over simplified it)

Comment: @BobS . . . The same idea should work.  I mean, you might want to limit the difference to just "batch" rows but that seems like a minor change (a `case` expression).

Comment: Thank you Gordon, could you indicate what that may look like code wise? Many thanks

Comment: @BobS . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a follow-on question about different data, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Will do. The above errors with Datediff requires three parts

Comment: @BobS . . . Your question is tagged "mysql" and in MySQL `datediff()` has two arguments.

Comment: Apologies I am using Microsoft SQL Server. I believed that both SQL and Mysql where the same. Oops.

The SQL server doesn't like "as"
Updated question with complex table is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772589/calculate-difference-using-nearest-oldest-date-using-same-column-with-a-comple